# What does "Runtime error 5692" mean?

Tags: vba, runtime-error

The error "Runtime error 5692" gets thrown by `range.Find.Execute` under some circumstances, including sometimes when the range is empty, and sometimes when a regex search is done with a malformed regex.

What does this error mean? Is the error documented anywhere?  From my position of ignorance, it is unpredictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research, but—like you—I found no documentation.
[It appears](http://www.officekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/word-vba/5804/Using-Find-Replace-text-as-a-variable) that this error can sometimes be caused by not clearing find/replace text.

I have tested the code below with several different inputs, and it is running without errors.
Note: code requires checking Tools -> References -> Microsoft Word xx.0 Object Library.

```
Sub TextReplace()

    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oFind As Find

    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add("C:\in.doc")
    Set oFind = oDoc.Range.Find

    oFind.Execute "foo", , , , , , , , , "bar", wdReplaceAll

    oDoc.SaveAs ("C:\out.doc")
    oDoc.Close
    oWord.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Feel free to update your question with any errors you get while running this code.

Comment: Great link - yes, that might be what's behind all of the cases I've seen. I'll check this out.

Comment: Accepted, solves my problem, although I'm still not quite sure what's going on: it seems like this error should be called "Find freaked out about its internal state", and something like adapting Helmut Weber's Resetsearch subroutine (e.g., at http://www.ms-news.net/f4081/wddialogeditfind-issue-133861.html) is the way to ensure the state is not too weird for VBA.  I still don't have enough of a picture of what confuses VBA's Find to be able to predict when it will fall over; maybe that's worth putting up a bounty for.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my testing with Word 2007 (under Crossover FWIW), I think this is occurring when the "Find" text (Find.Text) contains invalid characters for the Find.MatchWildcards flag. That flag is sticky, so if the user happened to use it on their last manual find or find/replace the VBA script would be contaminated with that sticky setting, resulting in the runtime error 5692 when you use characters such as '^p' and '^t' in your Find.Text string. Explicitly setting "Find.MatchWildcards = False" before running Find.Execute prevents the error. You'd think we could have had some documentation or a better error message though.

Test case that always fails:

```
Sub ReplaceInDocument
  Dim wdReplaceAll
  'set the value for the replace "constant"
  wdReplaceAll = 2
  With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "replacement text "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = 1
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
  'the Replace argument is the 11'th argument
    .Execute , , , , , , , , , , wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```

Test case that works:

```
Sub ReplaceInDocument
  Dim wdReplaceAll
  'set the value for the replace "constant"
  wdReplaceAll = 2
  With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "replacement text "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = 1
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
  'the Replace argument is the 11'th argument
    .Execute , , , , , , , , , , wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```